# TypeScript, Angular 1.x: How to avoid excessive initialization / definition of class values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm just beginning the process of converting an Angular 1.x app from vanilla JS to TypeScript. This is my first foray into the TS + Angular world, so my understanding is extremely limited.

I've gone through a couple video tutorials from PluralSight, and I've tried my hand at Googling at well. However, I have yet to find a more succinct way to prepare values that will be used in a class. It seems like this has to be done **3x!!!**

[image]

Am I missing something?

**Is there a more succinct method for preparing a controller's values?**

Comment: Why the interface? That's1x off right there.

Comment: Right, the interface is absolutely redundant. I think you should read more about OOP design, that's what is problem with the your code.

Comment: no need to repeat `this dot` numerous times when you can create a simple object and extend controller with it

Comment: @charlietfl, would you be able to post an example of creating a simple object and extending the controller with it? When I remove the `this dot`, I get compile errors from other places in the code similar to `Cannot find name 'thatValueYouJustRemovedThisFrom'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.thatValueYouJustRemovedThisFrom'?` @noppa, @lapuckire the interface provides me the ability to ensure that other classes with similar functionality implement the required values.